# What is class of "p" here ? class of "p" is double or cell?

Tags: matlab

My code is below

```
r=1*10^3
c=1*10^-6
num=[-1]
dnum=[r*c 0]
sys=tf(num,dnum)
num1=[-r*c 0]
dnum1=[1]
sys1=tf(num1,dnum1)
subplot(211)
step(sys)
subplot(212)
step(sys1)
[z,p,k]=zpkdata(sys1)
```

I was running above script but when I get output, I see `double` written in my output matrix `p`. I have highlighted in attached snapshot:

[image]

When I type `whos` on command prompt, I see that the class of `p` is `cell` as shown highlighted:
[image]

Is `p` of type `double` or `cell`?

Comment: From the documentation for `zpkdata`: "_The outputs z and p are cell arrays_". What is confusing you is that when you type `p` in the console, Matlab shows you the _content_ of the cell array `p`, the content of the cell array being a `[0x1 double]` array (empty as it happens).

Comment: Its a cell that contains a double inside.

Comment: means,using two classes(cell & double) simultaneously?